# ProGuard does not obfuscate Bluetooth classes

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, proguard

I am using `ProGuard` in Android to obfuscate my code. My application uses the Android Bluetooth API and  the following is a portion of my entire code snippet

```
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }

    //more code over here
}
```

When I enabled ProGuard and tried obfuscating my code I see the following output using the `Java decompiler`

[image: Output]

My question is why isn't the `BluetoothAdapter` class obfuscated. Why doesn't ProGuard add its own naming to the default classes like `BluetoothAdapter`. Do I need to add any arguments to the configuration file in order to obfuscate the adapter class or is this not possible?

Please help me solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BluetoothAdapter` class is part of the android API (`android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter`), proguard cannot obfuscate references to it otherwise the VM wouldn't have any way to know that you are using this class. The obfuscation is only done on your classes, without tampering with classes you don't control.

Comment: so in that case ProGuard would never obfuscate all classes from the android.* package right?

Comment: do other obfuscation tools work the same as ProGuard? or are  there other tools that can obfuscate `BluetoothAdapter`

Comment: Those classes are not embarked within the apk but are available at runtime in the classpath, you don't have control over them.